# What is the difference between util.pump(streamA, streamB) and streamA.pipe(streamB)?

Tags: node.js, stream

The source code looks very similar: [`pump`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L447-482), [`pipe`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/stream.js#L33-122). Why would I use one instead of the other? Is one simply a better version of the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream.pipe is now the preferred method apparently since 0.3.x so try and use that when possible

sources:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/FwdDQvAf4xM

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591335/424851

Answer (score 3):

There are two significant difference between the two. The first is that the `util.pump` method can operate on two "stream-like" objects, while the `Stream.prototype.pipe` assumes that they *are* stream objects. The second is because of that assumption, the `pipe` can be chained ( `streamA | streamB | streamC` ) while the former can't (easily).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: 28/04/2020**

It's worth to say that `pump` is only necessary for Node.js 8.x or earlier, as for Node.js 10.x or later version, [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback) is introduced to replace for `pump`. This is a module method to pipe between streams forwarding errors and properly cleaning up and provide a callback when the pipeline is complete.