# What is the difference between pump and pipe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Experienced node js devs often recommend to use [npm pump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pump) module instead of node [Stream.pipe](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) method.

Why would I use one instead of the other?

There is a [similar looking question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726507/what-is-the-difference-between-util-pumpstreama-streamb-and-streama-pipestre) but its 6 years old. Its node 9.8.0 already and I guess things changed from that time.

Comment: The old SO question is about `pump` which is completely unrelated to the module `pump` (by mafintosh).

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: use [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback)

As for Node.js 10.x or later version, pipeline is introduced to replace for pump. This is a module method to pipe between streams **forwarding errors and properly cleaning up** and provide a callback when the pipeline is complete.

But what's the difference between `pipe` and `pipeline`?
You can find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459320/5732327)

Answer (score 0):

From the `pump` README:

> When using standard `source.pipe(dest)` `source` will not be destroyed if `dest` emits close or an error. You are also not able to provide a callback to tell when then pipe has finished.