# What's the difference between .pipe and pipeline on streams

Tags: node.js, stream

I found two different ways to pipe streams in node.js

Well known `.pipe()` method of a stream

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

and standalone function for streams

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback

Which one should I use and what are the benefits between those two?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TL;DR - You better want to use `pipeline`

> What's pipeline?

[From the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback): A module method to pipe between streams **forwarding errors and properly cleaning up** and provide a callback when the pipeline is complete.

> What's the motivation for using pipeline?

❌
Let's take a look at the following code:

```
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const server = createServer(
  (req, res) => {
    createReadStream(__filename).pipe(res);
  }
);

server.listen(3000);
```

What's wrong here?
If the response will quit or the client closes the connection - then the **read stream is not closed or destroyed**, which leads to a memory leak.

✅So if you use `pipeline`, it would close all other streams and make sure that there are no memory leaks.

```
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');

const server = createServer(
  (req, res) => {
    pipeline(
      createReadStream(__filename),
      res,
      err => {
        if (err)
          console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
        else
          console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
      }
    );
  }
);

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: The documentation also states that this almost exact example prohibits you from interacting with `res`. So you can't send back a `500` status since when `createReadStream` closes, it will close `res` as well. *Then* it calls the callback. That doesn't mean it's "bad". Just beware.

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation, they both do the same thing. But there some differences:

- `.pipe()` is a method of `Readable`, while `pipeline` is a module method of `stream` that accepts streams to pipe.
- `pipeline()` method provide a callback when the pipeline is complete.
- `pipeline()` method was added since 10 version of node, while `.pipe` exist from the earliest versions of Node.

In my opinion, with `pipeline()` code looks a bit cleaner, but you can use both of them.

Example of `.pipe()`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const r = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');
const z = zlib.createGzip();
const w = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt.gz');
r.pipe(z).pipe(w);
```

Example of `pipeline()`:

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

pipeline(
  fs.createReadStream('archive.tar'),
  zlib.createGzip(),
  fs.createWriteStream('archive.tar.gz'),
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

**pipeline** is the improved version of **pipe** it was added to stream module since Node.js v10

Also, **pipeline** takes any number of arguments and the last argument is a callback used to know when the pipeline ends or throws an error.

Usage pipe:

```
mySourceStream.pipe(myStream).pipe(anotherStream)
```

Usage pipeline:

```js
mySourceStream.pipeline(myStream, anotherStream, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There is an error')
  } else {
    console.log('pipeline successful')
  }
})
```